# React / Next - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'compat')

Tags: reactjs, next.js

All of a sudden I am getting an issue when trying to run npm build.

The error I get is as follows (for all pages):

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/sharelink/Index". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'compat')
> Build error occurred
Error: Export encountered errors on following paths
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "nextjstemplate",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -p 14009",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p 14009",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "postinstall": "npm run prepare",
    "eslint": "eslint \"**/*.+(js|jsx|ts|tsx)\"",
    "eslint:fix": "eslint --fix \"**/*.+(js|jsx|ts|tsx)\"",
    "prettier": "prettier --check \"**/*.+(js|jsx|ts|tsx|json|yml|yaml|md|css|scss)\"",
    "prettier:fix": "prettier --write \"**/*.+(js|jsx|ts|tsx|json|yml|yaml|md|css|scss)\"",
    "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.0",
    "@emotion/server": "^11.10.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.0",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.9.10",
    "@mui/base": "^5.0.0-alpha.105",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.6",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.3",
    "@mui/system": "^5.10.10",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.8",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.6",
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "cookies-next": "^2.1.1",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "dompurify": "^2.4.3",
    "html-react-parser": "^3.0.8",
    "lottie-react": "^2.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "next": "^12.3.0",
    "next-progress": "^2.2.0",
    "next-pwa": "5.5.4",
    "nextjs-progressbar": "^0.0.14",
    "notistack": "^2.0.8",
    "pm2": "^5.2.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.40.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-share": "^4.4.1",
    "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.1",
    "sass": "^1.54.5",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@commitlint/cli": "^17.1.2",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^17.1.0",
    "cypress": "^10.6.0",
    "eslint": "8.22.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.2.5",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-css-modules": "^2.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-mui-path-imports": "^0.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.10",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^2.0.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.1",
    "lint-staged": "^13.0.3",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "./*/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}": [
      "npm run prettier:fix",
      "npm run eslint:fix"
    ],
    "*.{json,md}": [
      "npm run prettier:fix"
    ]
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  }
}
```

Just to add to the above, the error seems more likely to be in relation to emotion.

```
   error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'compat')
        at /var/www/vhosts/staging-site.co.uk/node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-react.cjs.dev.js:190:29
        at /var/www/vhosts/staging-site.co.uk/node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-b63ca7c6.cjs.dev.js:66:16
```

Any ideas on what is the cause for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This issue is caused by an update in `@mui/styled-engine` that apparently removes the CacheProvider from emotion.

You can force the resolution of this package to a previous version in the package.json as a workaround meanwhile the issue is not being fixed.

```
{
   ...,
   "resolutions": {
     "@mui/styled-engine": "5.11.0"
   }
}
```

You can track the status of the issue here: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/36096

Comment: Many thanks @crodriguezanton, the link helped a lot, what ended up being the fix was removing injectFirst from my index.jsx <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>. Thank you so much :)